# Modal popup not showing with runat=server on <div>

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I hope this is a simple one for someone to answer.

If i have a button that allows a user to edit something on the page, they can click on

> `<a href="#editpage" data-toggle="modal">Edit this page</a>`

This then opens a modal on the page with the following DIV

```
<div id="editpage" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    This is the content in my modal
</div>
```

The issue I am having is that when I add a *runat="server"* to the modal's div tag, so that I can determine if the user can even see/inspect the page source if they are not a moderator,, that the modal no longer pops up when i click on my edit button.

Is there anything I can do so that I can still control if the modal is rendered from code-behind based on logic there, and still have the edit to modal click function still work without turning it into a server control.

Comment: Check the rendered html.  Been a while, but doesn't adding `runat=server` change the `id=` on the `div` to make it a server-side unique id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer which was to wrap the modal div in another div or placeholder tag and then control that from the server side controls. This meant that the modal's div did not have it's ID modified due to the server side assignment and therefore I am now able to remove this markup entirely if the user is not a moderator.

```
<asp:Panel ID="editpage_panel" runat="server" Visible="false">
 -- modal here
</asp:Panel>
```